# Using leaflet.FreeDraw with leaflet.path.drag

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am wondering if it's possible to use [Leaflet.FreeDraw](https://github.com/Wildhoney/Leaflet.FreeDraw) with [leaflet.path.drag](https://github.com/Leaflet/Path.Drag.js) to be able to drag the polygon created by FreeDraw plugin.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkbvy706/)

I tried to enable dragging plugin like this, but it doesn't work.

```
const map = new L.Map(document.querySelector('section.map'), { doubleClickZoom: false }).setView(LAT_LNG, 14);
L.tileLayer(TILE_URL).addTo(map);
const freeDraw = new FreeDraw({ mode: FreeDraw.ALL });
map.addLayer(freeDraw);

freeDraw.dragging.enable();
```

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by not working, you should be able to drag individual markers on the map, I can drag it. Are you expecting it to drag entire polygone?

Comment: I am talking about dragging polygon, not markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the bounds from the `FreeDraw` by listening to the `markers` event to create a [polygon](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#polygon) or other map object using leaflet enabled with `dragging`. See working example below.

You should consider whether you would like to disable the `FreeDraw after this`, using the option `leaveModeAfterCreate:true` as the user may get additional polygons when dragging

```js
const LAT_LNG = [51.505, -0.09];
const TILE_URL = 'https://cartodb-basemaps-a.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png';

const map = new L.Map(document.querySelector('section.map'), { doubleClickZoom: false }).setView(LAT_LNG, 14);
L.tileLayer(TILE_URL).addTo(map);
const freeDraw = new FreeDraw({ 
mode: FreeDraw.ALL,
leaveModeAfterCreate:true //recommended to prevent undesired creation of multiple polygons
});
map.addLayer(freeDraw);

//freeDraw.dragging.enable();

//STEP 1: Listen to markers event raised by free draw whenever edits (create/edit/deletions are made to the map)
freeDraw.on("markers",function(event){
  //we are only interested in create events
  //we aim to extract the bounds and remove the existing
  //  freedraw references. If it is that you would like your
  //  user to edit the polygon, then you may keep these and do the   //  additional work to manage and update these references
  if(event.eventType=='create' && event.latLngs.length > 0){ 
  
     //capture the current polygon bounds (store in 1st position)
     var latLngs = event.latLngs[0];
     freeDraw.clear(); //clear freedraw markers
     //create polygon from lat lng bounds retrieved
     var polygon = L.polygon(
         latLngs.map(function(latLng){
             return [latLng.lat,latLng.lng];
         }), {
            color: 'red',
            draggable: true //make polygon draggable
         }).addTo(map);
     
  
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.map {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.map.mode-create {
    cursor: crosshair;
}

.leaflet-edge {
    background-color: #95bc59;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: move;
    outline: none;
    transition: background-color .25s;
}

.leaflet-polygon {
    fill: #b4cd8a;
    stroke: #50622b;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill-opacity: .75;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.2/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.2/leaflet-src.js"></script>


<script src="https://rawgit.com/Wildhoney/Leaflet.FreeDraw/master/dist/leaflet-freedraw.iife.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet.path.drag/src/Path.Drag.js"></script>
<section class="map"></section>
```

**NB. Also see working example on js-fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/ytevLbgs/**